# Angular fire Query for a boolean value does not display anything

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I have a collection called orders and I want to query it to only show the orders which have the field orderCompleted set to false. However when I use the .where it does not display anything.

```
  orders: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.orders = firestore.collection('Order', ref=>
    ref.where("orderCompleted", "==", false)
    .orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Since `valuechanges()` return an observable you'll want to subscribe to it (or use async pipe)

Comment: How would I do this? It was working fine when I just had the .orderBy then once I added the .where is when it stopped displaying anything

Comment: As mentioned above, `orders` will only start emitting values upon subscription. Is data being displayed once you remove the query? i.e. ` this.orders = firestore.collection('Order').valueChanges()`

Comment: values where being displayed before I included the .where. The data was being displayed correctly when I had,

 export class OrdersComponent {
  orders: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.orders = firestore.collection('Order', ref=>
    ref.orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the following inside a service class:

```
constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore){}
getOrders(){
 return firestore.collection('Order', ref=> ref.where("orderCompleted", "==", false).orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();
}
```

Then inside the component, you can inject the service to the constructor of the component class and then `subscribe` to the `observable` and get the result:

```
constructor(private service : Service){}
ngOnInit(){
   this.service.getOrders().subscribe(data =>{
     console.log(data);
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said. im getting an error on the 'getOrders'. 
`export class OrdersComponent {
  orders: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(private service: FirestoreDataService) {}
    ngOnInit(){
      this.service.getOrders().subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data)
      });
    }
  }`

Error An argument for 'firestore' was not provided.

Comment: did you put `firestore: AngularFirestore` in your service constructor ?

Comment: Service code 
`export class FirestoreDataService {
  constructor(public firestore: AngularFirestore) {}
    getOrders(){
      return firestore.collection('Order', ref=> ref.where("orderCompleted", "==", false).orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();
    }
getCompletedOrders(){
  return firestore.collection('Order', ref=> ref.where("orderCompleted", "==", true).orderBy('collectionTime', 'asc')).valueChanges();
}

}`

Comment: Orders Component
`export class OrdersComponent {
  orders: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(private service: FirestoreDataService) {}
    ngOnInit(){
      this.service.getOrders().subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data)
      });
    }
  }`


Sorry for the hassle its for my uni dissertation project

Comment: it should be `this.firestore`

Comment: Hi ive had no luck, it is now telling me, FirebaseError: [code=failed-precondition]: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https:.. However I need the data to be queried in real time and from what I read creating this index won't do this. Is there any other ways around this? I just need the queried data to be displayed on bootstrap cards

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1327 just flow the link provided in the error

Comment: How do I fix the index problem? when I use the link provided in the error it just shows a loading symbol but does not do anything ie.does not create an index.

Comment: Please check Doug answer in your other question, the index is out of scope of this question.